# Library Files Not Found, even though they are listed in ldconfig

Tags: linux, libraries, ncurses

This is a head scratcher.

Below is the output of `ldconfig -p | grep libncur*` :

```
libncursesw.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so.5
libncursesw.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so
libncurses.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5
libncurses.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5
libncurses.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libncurses.so.5
libncurses.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libncurses.so
```

This is the error I get:

```
/cass/bin/m050ub02: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Clearly the libraries are listed in the ldconfig cache, but it can't seem to find them.

Comment: What do `file /cass/bin/m050ub02` and `ldd /cass/bin/m050ub02` output?

Comment: is the calling process overriding LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" - you could run it under `strace` to show us the path(s) it is trying to open.  Use `strace -e open` if there is too much output to find it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
strace -e open /cass/bin/m050ub02
```

this should tell you what the binary is trying to open.  Also try

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and see if your libraries are in there.  If not, try symlinking them somewhere on that path.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved. It turns out they were 64-bit libraries, I found a 32-bit, and everything works perfectly now.

Comment: There's something wrong with your configuration. A program should not be looking for 32-bit libraries in `/usr/lib64`.